Using variables within methods of same class without sending it as arguments or parameters
I want to read the json file and get the values separately in string and pass it on to the web application fields. Below is the program which i am trying to execute. In readfile method, i am parsing a json file and returning it in JSONArray.
i want to get only the nickname from the array with the parameter ID (array index). e.g getnickname(0) gives oth index nickname. But only the id is provided in the argument. I have tried by providing array as argument and i am able to achieve my goal. But how can i do it only ID argument.
Program:
package jsonprogram;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class FieldLocator {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static Object obj;
public static JSONObject jo;
//public static JSONArray address;
String baseUrl ="https://webapps.tekstac.com/AddressBook/";

public WebDriver createDriver()
{
driver=DriverSetup.getWebDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);
return driver;
}

public JSONArray ReadFile(String FileName) throws IOException, ParseException
{
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
FileReader reader=new FileReader(FileName);
JSONObject obj=(JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
String cover=(String) obj.get("cover");
System.out.println(cover);
JSONArray array=(JSONArray) obj.get("Addresses");
JSONArray address=new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
{
JSONObject jobj= (JSONObject) array.get(i);
address.add(i, jobj);
}
System.out.println(address);
return address; 
}

public String getNickName(int id)
{   
//i have to write the code to fetch the nickname from array
}
public String getContactName(int id)
{   
//i have to write the code to fetch the contact name from array
}
public String getCity(int id)
{   
//i have to write the code to fetch the city from array
}
public String getType(int id)
{   
//i have to write the code to fetch the Type from array
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException 
{
FieldLocator fl=new FieldLocator();
String Filename="D:\\Exercise\\Teksatc\\src\\main\\java\\jsonprogram\\AddressBook.json";        
JSONArray result=fl.ReadFile(Filename);
int count=result.size();
System.out.println(count);
for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
{
String nname=fl.getNickName(j);
System.out.println(nname);
}
}
}

JSON File:
{
"cover": "AddressBook", 
"Addresses":
[
{
"id":"1",
"NickName": "Rahul",
"ContactName": "Dravid",
"Company":"Cricket",
"City":"Indore",
"Country":"India",
"Type":"Address"
},
{
"id":"2",
"NickName": "Sachin",
"ContactName": "Tendulkar",
"Company":"Cricket",
"City":"Mumbai",
"Country":"India",
"Type":"Address"
}
]
}

I am not sure how is this possible. So i have no idea about trying multiple ways.

Save the JSONArray returned by the ReadFile() function into a class level variable in the FieldLocatorClass (you look like you're close, you have a variable you could use that's currently commented out!).  Then you can reference that variable in the "get" functions becuase they are member functions of that class.

Please indent your code properly if you expect someone else to read it. It will make it a lot more easier for you too though...

Make any variable you want to transfer between methods in a class as a global variable. So in your case, have an array as a global variable(like the one u have commented out). in the readFile method, store the array in that global variable. then you can access it anywhere. so for example, in the getnickname(int id) method, you can simply return address[id].

When I uncomment the array address declared at a class level , i am getting the below error at the statement "address.add(i, jobj);" and the address array is null in console.
Error: Type safety: The method add(int, Object) belongs to the raw type ArrayList. References to generic type ArrayList should be parameterized

Also,  i need to pass the return values from get functions into the website and get the success message and display in console. Please pour in your suggesstions.
